# Auth::validate returns false Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

Well i am trying to do a authentication via Laravel using Auth::validate($credenciais); and its not working.

```
public function LoginData(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required|email',
            'pwd'=> 'required',
        ]);

        $credenciais = $request->only('username','pwd');

        dd(Auth::validate($credenciais));
    }
```

I try to login with username:teste@teste and pwd=teste and he returns me false when should be true.

in database:

teste@teste $2y$10$UzU3EUMdt3EcZ9.1YtkLrO5XOTfCy7C0odIJVblkLbCCveA2BoVVy     <---- Hashed password using Hash::make('teste);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array sent to `Auth::validate()` must have the indexes `email` and `password`. (if you are using default auth of laravel)

```
$credenciais = ['email' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->pwd];

dd(Auth::validate($credenciais));
```

Comment: i have made some changes in my SQL i didnt had ID now i have it, ty for ur time!